# Nested template functions with their own template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, variadic

Say I have a class that has some templated arguments, and a function that can access each one of those arguments such as

```
template <typename... Types>
class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename Type>
    Type& get() { return std::get<Type>(member_tuple); }

protected:
    std::tuple<Types...> member_tuple;
};
```

And I want to use this class as a base class and specialize the `get()` function in the child class to do something ... special ... but not so specialized as to define any of the template arguments just yet. Perhaps something like this:

```
template <typename... Types>
class Bar
    : public Foo<Types...>
{
public:
    template <typename Type>
    Type& special_get() 
    {
        // do your special thing in here somewhere.
        return Foo<Types...>::get<Type>(this->member_tuple); 
    }
};
```

However, that's a compiler error: it complains that it expected
`return Foo<Types...>::get(this->member_tuple)`.

To confuse me further, if I leave out the `<Type>` argument, and then try to call that function, I get a "couldn't deduce template parameter 'Type'" error instead.

How do I go about passing the additional template argument to the wrapped base class function?